# Is "affineTransform" a valid CALayer keypath for setting up CABasicAnimation

Tags: ios, calayer, cgaffinetransform, cabasicanimation

This seems like a really basic question that has been surprisingly hard to find an answer to.

CABasicAnimations set up with "affineTransform" as the keypath haven't worked for me, and in a bunch of places I've seen people eventually resorting to use CATransform3D instead with the "transform" keypath. Sure that's a hint, but it would be good to have confirmation if "affineTransform" is meant to work or not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Technically, `affineTransform` [is not a property of CALayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500-CH1-SW70), and is documented as a "convenience method" wrapper around the `transform` property, which [is documented as animatable](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500-CH1-SW9).

It's only really by objective-c's implicit conversion of keypaths to selectors that it appears affineTransform behaves like a property when use (under most circumstances) in a keypath. However, the CA libraries are setup to observe only certain keypaths, and that's not one of them :-)

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for confirming.